# Activator.CreateInstance returning incorrect type?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'd be grateful if you could help with this:

1. I have a base class for a Provider.
2. This is subclassed to create a
   DefaultProvider.
3. DefaultProvider implements an interface called “IExportProvider”
4. DefaultProvider is subclassed to create a
   DanishProvider.

The base class has various virtual methods that return string values in English.
The DanishProvider overrides these to return strings in Danish.

At runtime, I load either the DefaultProvider or the DanishProvider depending on a config. value. I do this by scanning the current assembly for the type name, which is either “DefaultProvider” or “DanishProvider”, and which implements “IExportProvider”

`var importServiceType = assembly.DefinedTypes.FirstOrDefault(type => (type.Name.Equals(providerServiceName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) && type.ImplementedInterfaces.Any(i => i == typeof(I)));`

I then use Activator.CreateInstance to create an instance of the type:

`return (IExportProvider)Activator.CreateInstance(importServiceType, …)`

**Problem**

I use the code in a .Net 4.8 Web application, where I load the DanishProvider. This mostly works OK and I can see the Danish strings are returned. However, occasionally (after several days) the application appears to incorrectly load the DefaultProvider, and I see English strings returned.

Once it has switched to English it appears to stay on the DefaultProvider.

- Twice I have done an IISRESET which fixes the problem immediately.
- The settings
  are not being changed.
- There is only one type in the assembly called “DanishProvider”
- The code is executing on a single UAT server. I have not seen the issue on my local PC.
- I do not believe that the issue is related to caching.

Q. Is there a problem with the code approach described above?

Thank you

Comment: Where does the type name, the one used in search, come from?

Comment: What is the format of `providerServiceName`? If it is in an external assembly and you provide the assembly-qualified type name, or if its in the same assembly, the namespace-qualified type name,  `Type.GetType` combined with `Activator.CreateInstance` should work.  Maybe like: `return (IExportProvider)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(providerServiceName));`  Id also point out that you could also just resolve this with dependency injection, you'd just directly register the Interface->Type relationship with an if/else to drive the implementation type, the config value just drives the logic.

Comment: The type name comes from config. It is a simple name like "DanishProvider". All classes described above are in the same assembly.